# Changing cell colour if value modified in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am working in google sheets and want the background colour of the cell to change to red if it's value has been modified. However, I want to avoid using any script for that. Is it possible to do this through conditional formatting?
If not, is there any other way to do it? (again no scripts)

Answer (score 0):

this can't be done without a script because there is no way how to track down a "modified value". conditional formatting can be done based on something eg "something" stands for a fixed point in a timeline from which can change be anchored like today's date, max from range, equal to a value, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Possible with Conditional Formatting provided there is a record somewhere of the cell's initial value (the reference for what constitutes a change). This need not be in the same sheet. Say that reference is a named range `Tigger` that represents the 'initial' value of say C6 in the sheet with the cell whose colour is to be changed.

Select C6 then Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if..., Custom formula is:

```
=$C$6<>indirect("Tigger")
```

choose red fill and click <kbd>Done</kbd>.

The colour is lost if the cell returns to the initial value (unless the content of the named range is modified to have itself been changed meanwhile).